# C++: capitalizing a character using another character

Tags: c++, text, character

I'm trying to make a function that capitalizes the next character in a string after I input a "^" character. the code looks like this:

```
void decodeshift( string orig, string search, string replace )
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    while (true) {
    pos = orig.find(search, pos);
    if(pos == string::npos)
        break;
    orig.erase(pos, search.length());
    orig.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);

    cout<<orig<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string question = "What is the message? ";
    string answer = "The real message is ";

    string shift="^";
    string test="a";

    string answer1;

    //output decoded message
    string answer2;

    cout << question;
    cin >> answer1;
    cout << "decoding . . . " << "\n";

    //decodeback(answer1, back);
    decodeshift(answer1, shift, test);
    return 0;
}
```

my input will be:

```
^hello
```

desired output:

```
Hello
```

current output

```
aello
```

I can't seem to find the correct function to use and I'm confused on how to use toupper in a situation like this. I just need to find the proper replacement.

Comment: You might consider taking a little bit of time to read through the tour and work on a [mcve]. `toupper` is fine for this, but since your code doesn't compile it's hard to know why you're having trouble with it.

Comment: i tried using a placeholder string instead of the uppercase, and it worked fine. I'm just looking for a way to use toupper instead of an individual character unless I use 26 separate if statements.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper know about this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about placeholder strings or 26 if statements. This is a simple problem, and I'm sure we could help you solve it, but you need to provide your real compilable code first so we can see what's going on. https://ideone.com/dJZCBI

Comment: Fixed it, so whenever "^" appears, the next character is replaced by "a". So I'm just trying to find a way to make it uppercase instead.

Comment: This is not your code. It cannot be. You reference a function named `decodeshift`, but all I see is a function named `shift`. It does not output "aello" because it cannot compile. See @RetiredNinja's comment about a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Not trying to be harsh, but these are the facts.

Comment: I was able to fix it, apologies, not in the best environment for coding right now :(

Comment: @helpmeimpoor so, what is stopping you from simply using `toupper()` instead of using `orig.replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
#include <cctype>

void decodeshift( string orig, string search )
{
    size_t pos = orig.find(search);
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        orig.erase(pos, search.length());
        if (pos == orig.size()) break;
        orig[pos] = (char) std::toupper( (int)orig[pos] );
        pos = orig.find(search, pos + 1);
    }
    return orig;
}

...

answer1 = decodeshift(answer1, "^");
cout << answer1 << endl;
```

Or, simply get rid of the `shift` parameter:

```
#include <cctype>

string decodeshift( string orig )
{
    size_t pos = orig.find('^');
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        orig.erase(pos, 1);
        if (pos == orig.size()) break;
        orig[pos] = (char) std::toupper( (int)orig[pos] );
        pos = orig.find('^', pos + 1);
    }
    return orig;
}

...

answer1 = decodeshift(answer1);
cout << answer1 << endl;
```